# fetch in node js gives TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

A simple fetch in node js gives error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**,
I went through many answers here, everywhere it mentions to return the Promise, but in this case, the returned promise object is chained immediately with then(), below is the code.

```
const fetch = require("fetch").fetchUrl

fetch('http://example.com/movies.json').then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: [`fetchUrl`](https://github.com/andris9/fetch/blob/c58142f56de8406a68b99e747391575e6bda949f/lib/fetch.js#L377-L451) doesn't return *anything*, certainly not a promise. [As documented](https://github.com/andris9/fetch#fetch-from-url) it accepts a callback.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch  looks like rather than using `then()` you have to give it a callback

Comment: If you are hoping to use the WHATWG Promise-based `fetch` API as you can in a browser, you should use a different package, e.g., https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch is one

Comment: so which package should I use to make the fetch work with Promises in node js, instead of callbacks?

Comment: Thanks, guys, one mistake I did was, I did not go through the docs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fetch module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch) does not use Promises, it uses traditional node-style callbacks. You can promisify the function using [util.promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original):

```
const fetch = require("util").promisify(require("fetch").fetchUrl)
```

Note that this fetch module hasn't been updated for 4 years. I recommend using a more updated fetch module that supports promises like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch), [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got), or [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) if you'd like to use promises.

Comment: I suspect that `promisify` will only give you access to `meta`, not also the `body`. Also `request` is now deprecated: https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

Comment: @jonrsharpe Oops, yes, you're correct. I didn't realize the callback has three parameters.

Answer (score 1):

It look like [fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fetch) doesn't use promises, rather it uses callbacks.

So to do what you're looking to do you'd need to do this:

```
fetchUrl("http://example.com/movies.json", function(error, meta, body){
    console.log(JSON.parse(body));
});
```

If you aren't using the package I linked let me know, but from what I can tell fetch doesn't use promises and this is the first thing I found on NPM.

Comment: so which package should I use to make the fetch work with Promises in node js, instead of callbacks?

Comment: Look at the packages that Klaycon put in his answer, those might help. Though it loks like [node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch) might be what you want

Answer (score 1):

Try the callback way:

```
const fetchUrl = require("fetch").fetchUrl

fetchUrl("http://kreata.ee/iso-8859-15.php", function(error, meta, body){
    console.log(body.toString());
});
```